# Why the query results did not come back when using UDF library in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: user-defined-functions, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I found that when using UDF function library in Apache IoTDB, the query result in Cli tool of IoTDB did not return the result data. Do I need to enable it by setting any parameter, and how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The UDF you use may not be registered in Apache IoTDB. There is a startup script on the official website that you can use to register UDF. Pay attention to the installation path of IoTDB, which may need to be modified to your own settings.